# Django - Saving a model using Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a simple model - the instances of which I will be saving through the admin interface.

The field **hashval** needs to have the hashed value of **title**. It seems to just have the default hashvalue for every entry. How do I fix that ? Additionally, it should also get updated when **title** is updated. Any help in achieving this will be much appreciated. (Please point out if any duplicates exist)

```
class Entry(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
content = models.TextField()
hashval = models.BigIntegerField()
hashval = abs(hash(title))

def __unicode__(self):
    return smart_unicode(self.title + " " + str(self.hashval))

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Entries'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to override your save method to apply this before it's saved.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    # Need to specify it as blank=True here or 
    # in the form so it can be ignored when the form is cleaned
    hashval = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hashval = abs(hash(self.title))
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry but I have another question as a follow up - How can I make this field hidden in the admin interface ? Thanks !